# typo3 flow: catch exception and forward back to originating action

Tags: flow-framework

In my typo3 flow app I want to stop execution after throwing an exception as flash-message. Therefore I wrote this:

```
public function updateAction(Mitglied $mitglied) {

   if ($xy == 'z') {
       try {
           throw new \TYPO3\Flow\Validation\Exception\InvalidValidationOptionsException('Fehler: In dieser Kombination nicht zulässig', 1);
       } catch (\TYPO3\Flow\Validation\Exception\InvalidValidationOptionsException $e) {
           $this->flashMessageContainer->addMessage(new \TYPO3\Flow\Error\Error($e->getMessage()));
       }
   }

   $this->mitgliedRepository->update($mitglied);
   $this->addFlashMessage('Mitglied erfolgreich geÃ¤ndert.');
   $this->redirect('index');
}
```

The message ist shown, as I wanted, as flash-message. But the execution of the function doesn't stop. Does anybody know, why and how to prevent? A redirect to the originating action would be desired for the case, that the if-condition is true.

Comment: "The message ist shown" ?

Comment: Yes; what I mean is that the message "Fehler: In dieser Kombination nicht zulässig" appears as flash-message. So obviously the exception gets catched but the function is executed although.

Comment: Your code does excactly what you tell it to. You're trying to throw an exception, then you catch it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I read [here](http://php.net/manual/de/language.exceptions.php), that the function is only executed, if there is no exception in the try-block or if there is no fitting catch for the exception. What I want to do is to validate, if the if-condition is false. If the if-condition is true, I want to show a flash-message in my app and the updateAction should stop at that point, so the user can adjust his input. If the if-condition is false, the updateAction should be executed.

Comment: I think I need somthing like the "errorAction" like described [here](http://typo3.org/api/flow/TYPO3/Flow/Mvc/Controller/class-ActionController.html#errorAction%28%29). "The default implementation sets a flash message, request errors and forwards back to the originating action." - that sounds good but I don´t have an idea, how to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now with the following code:

```
// get back to originating request - see https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.Flow.git/blob/master:/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Mvc/Controller/ActionController.php

$referringRequest = $this->request->getReferringRequest();
if ($referringRequest === NULL) {
      return;
}
$packageKey = $referringRequest->getControllerPackageKey();
$subpackageKey = $referringRequest->getControllerSubpackageKey();
if ($subpackageKey !== NULL) {
        $packageKey .= '\\' . $subpackageKey;
}
$argumentsForNextController = $referringRequest->getArguments();
$argumentsForNextController['__submittedArguments'] = $this->request->getArguments();
$argumentsForNextController['__submittedArgumentValidationResults'] = $this->arguments->getValidationResults();
$this->forward($referringRequest->getControllerActionName(), $referringRequest->getControllerName(), $packageKey, $argumentsForNextController);
```

In the end this is much easier:

```
$this->errorAction()->forwardToReferringRequest();
```